# db.collection is not a function with Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en#update_fields_in_nested_objects), we can use the dot notation with Firestore. When I run the following code in the client browser:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
let  db = getFirestore(app);
db.collection("users").doc("123").set({ name: "Mike"});
```

I get the following error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function`

I can't figure out where the problem comes from. Is the documentation up to date?

Answer (score 3):

I think that information's for a different version of Firebase. You're importing collection & doc as functions and they need to be run as such. Try the following

```
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
...
const db = getFirestore(app);
const usersCollection = collection(db, "users");
const docRef = doc(usersCollection, "123");
await updateDoc (docRef, { name: "Mike"});
```

Comment: Thx, Im' using Firebase 10.5.0, you think the information in the documentation is for a previous version?

Comment: I believe dot notation is no longer supported on the collection level, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71903525/7229259

Comment: got it, thank you for your help.

Comment: *firebaser here* Sorry for the confusion. The `.` notation is known as the namespaced API, and **is** still supported on newer releases through a set of `compat` libraries. For all on this, see the Firebase documentation on [upgrading from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).